# Vim's custom foldmarker {,} doesn't work

Tags: vim, fold, modeline

I have a js file with following content:

```
function do_this(){
    a = '{1}';
}

function do_that(a){
    b = b + 1;
}

// vim: set fdm=marker fmr={,} :
```

When it folds it shows following:

```
function do_this(){
    a = '{1}';
}

function do_that(a){ +-- 3 lines_____________

// vim: set fdm=marker fmr={,} :
```

I expect both functions to be folded. I guess "a = '{1}';" is getting in the way.
Is there a way to fix this using only the custom marker "{,}" within the modeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `foldmarker` does not allow regex matching, as specified by `:h fmr`. Therefore it will only match a literal string, so there's no way getting around the `a = '{1}'` in your example. However, it seems like what you really want is

```
// vim: set fdm=syntax fdls=1 :
```

with

```
let javaScript_fold=1
```

in your `~/.vimrc`.